# Codeigniter + HAuth, Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication, userid, hybridauth

I am using HybridAuth Library with Codeigniter Framework, All the other Social login are working properly Except "Facebook Social Login", I am getting the error "Authentication Failed! Facebook returned an invalid user Id."

I Tried all available Answers, Like:

- [Hybridauth Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824652/hybridauth-authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)
- [Hybridauth - PHP - Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068425/hybridauth-php-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)
- https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/188
- https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/633

I am struggling from 2 days, and tried all the possible answers, still can't figure it out what is the problem, any help will be really appreciable.

**Note:** CURL is working properly on my server

**Update**
**Code File** 
**config->hybridauthlib.php**

```
$config =
array(
    'base_url' => '/hauth/endpoint/',

    "providers" => array (
        "Facebook" => array (
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xxxxxxxx", "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxx" ),
        ),
);
```

**Thirdparty->hybridauth->config.php**

```
return 
array(
"base_url" => "/hauth/endpoint/", 
"Facebook" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" ),
            "trustForwarded" => true,
        ),
```

I have also do changes in **third_party->hybridauth->Hybrid->thirdparty->facebook->base_facebook.php**  as suggested by other developers

```
    public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
   );
   protected $trustForwarded = true;
   protected $allowSignedRequest = false;
```

**Facebook Redirect URIs**

```
http://localhost/myproj/index.php/hauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Facebook
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @Bestter : Question is updated with code file, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also found same issue and resolve it. Please go to this URL:
https://github.com/aviansh26dec/hauth

Comment: Hi, I download code from the link which you have provided, all the other logins are working fine except "facebook login", now getting the different error, **Sorry, Something went wrong**, is it a known issue? I already have clear the cache and tried on a different browser. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake I had put wrong Client Id, Thank you so much it's working now, But still, I can't figure it out what was the problem, another thing your app id and secret lay in the config file.